# Spring security OAuth2 - verify access token

Tags: spring, security, oauth-2.0

I was wondering what the best way of verifying the access token is using spring security?
The sparklr2 and tonr2 example end up using the session cookie to do the verification...so didn't have much to go off there.

Answer (score 0):

You could expose another endpoint at the auth server to do that for you.

If you'd like to use Spring only, it currently only supports sharing of the same DB between authorization server and resource server (see OAuth2ProtectedResourceFilter).

In any case, the spec doesn't mandate any one way. The way you choose would be on your preference or on your situation.